# postgresql socket file vanishes when assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sockets, ubuntu, rake

UPDATE: Server crashed after two hours of troubleshooting, and on restart, all assets compiled fine. But if anyone sees this and understands it better than me, any comments would still be appreciated.

When running `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`, I get the following:

```
rake aborted!  
could not connect to server: No such file or directory  
    Is the server running locally and accepting  
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

So I check the directory and the file doesn't exist. When I `service postgresql restart` the socket file appears in the expected directory. Looks like this:

```
/var/run/postgresql$ ll
total 8
drwxrwsr-x  2 postgres postgres 100 Sep 12 18:24 ./
drwxr-xr-x 23 root     root     760 Sep 12 17:29 ../
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres   5 Sep 12 18:24 9.1-main.pid
srwxrwxrwx  1 postgres postgres   0 Sep 12 18:24 .s.PGSQL.5432=
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  70 Sep 12 18:24 .s.PGSQL.5432.lock
```

But as soon as I run `rake` again, the rake fails and when I check the directory, the socket file has vanished.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove .lock file, then restart the server, May be it could help you.

Comment: I'll try that, but it seems like the .lock file is *already gone* when I restart the server.